# matlab libsvm multiclass one against all classification

Tags: matlab, classification, libsvm

I am new to classification and trying to do multiclass classification using libsvm. I have song features and want to classify then in 3 classes. Code works but the output (pred) give only one label for all test data. for example pred = [2;2;2;2]; 
Any change I do has not effect on output. I am not getting where I am going wrong. Can anyone help me out pls. Below is the code

```
load 113gender

s=cellstr(types);
[~,~,labels] = unique(s); 
data = allfeature;
numInst = size(data,1);
numLabels = max(labels);
numTest = size(alltest,1);

trainData = data;
trainLabel = labels;
testData = alltest;
%testLabel = ones(22,1);
%testLabel = [1;1;1;1;1;1;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;3;3;3;3;3;3;3;3];
testLabel = [3;3;3;3;3;3;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1];

%# train one-against-all models
model = cell(numLabels,1);
for k=1:numLabels
    model{k} = svmtrain(double(trainLabel==k), trainData, '-c 1 -g 0.2 -b 1');
end

%# get probability estimates of test instances using each model
prob = zeros(numTest,numLabels);
for k=1:numLabels
    [~,~,p] = svmpredict(double(testLabel==k), testData, model{k}, '-b 1');
    prob(:,k) = p(:,model{k}.Label==1);    %# probability of class==k
end

%# predict the class with the highest probability
[~,pred] = max(prob,[],2);
acc = sum(pred == testLabel) ./ numel(testLabel)  
C = confusionmat(testLabel, pred)
```

Comment: You don't have to explicitly train multi-class models unless you have to. LIBSVM will do this automatically for you. Regarding your code, your testing code doesn't look correct. What is `model{k}.Label==1`? Variable `model` is not a structure. Anyway, if you convert your `testLabel` in binary form then how can you get a probability distribution over three classes. You will get just two probabilities. Read up on how to implement your own one vs. all classification. Again, this is done in LIBSVM. Don't do it unless you have/want to.

Comment: Thanks sir for considering my question and reply. I did modification in model as per suggestion
load 113gender
s=cellstr(types);
[~,~,labels] = unique(s);
classes = labels;

train = allfeature;
test = alltest;
testLabel = [3;3;3;3;3;3;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1];

model = svmtrain(labels,train,'-c 1 -g 0.2 -b 1');

%%# Test
[predict_label, accuracy, prob_estimates] = svmpredict(testLabel, test, model, '-b 1');

Still getting same output = [2;2;2;2;2;2;2;2];  :( Please check for mistake
and testLabel values are 1,2 and 3.not binary.Can you please explain that more.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question instead of writing code in comments. Also, give the output of the following commands: 1. `whos labels` 2. `whos train` 3. `whos test`. Also provide value of `labels`.